# Converting bunch of TAB and TIF files into single GeoTIFF using GDAL?

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, tab

I have a number of TAB and TIF files. They form a single coverage. What I want to do is to convert all of them into a single GeoTIFF file, using GDAL tools, but I do not know how. I looked through dozens of threads, tutorials and etc., and it seems like GDAL supports TAB and TIF files, though I could not find any real example.

Comment: Let's suppose I have such files - one.tab, one.tif, two.tab, two.tif and want to get output.tiff. What GDAL utility should I use for this purpose and how the command would look like?

Comment: I believe you can find something useful among these answers http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=gdal+mosaic

Comment: I've already scanned through dozens threads, but could not find anything relative to TAB/TIF pair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a virtual mosaic of all .tab and .tif files using `gdalbuildvrt` and then convert the resulting VRT file to GeoTIFF with `gdal_translate`:

```
gdalbuildvrt -input_file_list my_list.txt mosaic.vrt
gdal_translate mosaic.vrt mosaic.tif
```

where `my_list.txt` is the input file list.

Comment: Many thanks! Would you be so kind to clarify the format of my_list.txt file. Should files go one by one in a single line or in a column. And should I list there just tif files or file names without extension?

Comment: And one tiny and I think the very last question - what if my tab files have coordinates in some local system and what I know about it is just proj4 formula. In other words I deal with a system which does not have a know SRID. Though, I know very well its proj4 formula

Comment: @Jacobian The files should be listed one by one in a single column with their relative path and extension. They should also have projection info attached in order to be mosaicked correctly.

Comment: Thansk! By files you mean just tif files or tab files as well?

Comment: Alternatively, if all your files to be mosaicked are contained in the same directory, you can simply execute something like: `gdalbuildvrt mosaic.vrt *.*` without creating an input file list.

Comment: Or, that is great! And would you be so kind to advise how can I attach projection to, say, one single tif, if the only thing I know is just proj4 formula? Is there a tool in GDAL which makes it possible?

Comment: To assign the SRS to a simple tif file (no GeoTIFF), you can use `gdalwarp`: `gdalwarp -s_srs 'EPSG:4326 -t_srs 'EPSG:4326' input.tif output.tif`